# I was testing my API the"GET" Request went fine, but when i tried the "POST" request it showed:405 "Method POST is not allowed" Django REST framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

> 405 Method Not Allowed
> "detail": "Method "POST" not allowed."

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from . models import Product 
from . serializers import ProductSerializer

@api_view(['GET'])
def product_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        products = Product.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

the `@api_view()` it's a decorator to declare valid HTTP methods to should respond in your function. You just add the `GET` method in the decorator so other methods like `POST` will be invalid and drf will respond `405 Not allowed`.

In this case, you should declare your decorator like this: `@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])`

For more information check [this link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view).